# How can I specify a regular expression in gradle.properties?

Tags: regex, groovy, gradle

I have the following definition in my `gradle.properties` file:

```
# A regular expression for extracting ticket numbers from commit messages       
ticketRegEx=AND-[0-9]+
```

It's used in a method like the following:

```
ext.getIssueNumbersFromLatestAlpha = { 
  def issueNumbers = [] 
  def commits = getCommitMessagesInRange('latest-alpha', 'HEAD')
  commits.each() { message ->
    def issueNumMatcher = message =~ /${project.ticketRegEx}/
    if (issueNumMatcher.size() > 0) {
      issueNumbers << issueNumMatcher[0].replace("(", "").replace(")", "")        }                                                                        }      
  return issueNumbers.toSet()
}
```

This works pretty well, but when I go to try and allow for a more general regex, things break down:

```
ticketRegEx=(\#[0-9]+)|(AND-[0-9]+)

./gradlew releaseNotes

* Where:
Build file '/Users/scottjohnson/Source/wheniwork-android/WhenIWork/build.gradle' line: 103

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':WhenIWork'.
> Could not find method getReleaseNotes() for arguments [alpha] on BuildType_Decorated{name=debug, debuggable=true, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, applicationIdSuffix=null, versionNameSuffix=-e506db5, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=false, signingConfig=SigningConfig_Decorated{name=debug, storeFile=/Users/scottjohnson/Source/wheniwork-android/debug.keystore, storePassword=android, keyAlias=wheniwork, keyPassword=android, storeType=/Users/scottjohnson/Source/wheniwork-android/debug.keystore}, embedMicroApp=false, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':WhenIWork'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:76)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$1.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:156)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:487)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method getReleaseNotes() for arguments [alpha] on BuildType_Decorated{name=debug, debuggable=true, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, applicationIdSuffix=null, versionNameSuffix=-e506db5, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=false, signingConfig=SigningConfig_Decorated{name=debug, storeFile=/Users/scottjohnson/Source/wheniwork-android/debug.keystore, storePassword=android, keyAlias=wheniwork, keyPassword=android, storeType=/Users/scottjohnson/Source/wheniwork-android/debug.keystore}, embedMicroApp=false, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:175)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at build_bkmx47wa6tcrmf0go4x11gcnv$_run_closure5_closure16_closure27.doCall(/Users/scottjohnson/Source/wheniwork-android/WhenIWork/build.gradle:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$ContainerElementsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:341)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:62)
    at build_bkmx47wa6tcrmf0go4x11gcnv$_run_closure5_closure16.doCall(/Users/scottjohnson/Source/wheniwork-android/WhenIWork/build.gradle:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.configure(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.configure(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.Action$execute.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension.buildTypes(BaseExtension.groovy:327)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated.buildTypes(Unknown Source)
    at build_bkmx47wa6tcrmf0go4x11gcnv$_run_closure5.doCall(/Users/scottjohnson/Source/wheniwork-android/WhenIWork/build.gradle:96)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage$ExtensionHolder.configure(ExtensionsStorage.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage.configureExtension(ExtensionsStorage.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:207)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:150)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
    at build_bkmx47wa6tcrmf0go4x11gcnv.run(/Users/scottjohnson/Source/wheniwork-android/WhenIWork/build.gradle:59)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:74)
    ... 46 more


BUILD FAILED
```

I think this has something to do with specifying my regular expression incorrectly, but the regex generation I'm using seems to indicate that the regular expression is correct, and will give me what I'm looking for. I think it might have something to do with the parentheses in `gradle.properties`, since specifying `(AND-[0-9]+)` as the `ticketRegEx` also generates the same exception.

Comment: Also, the following: `\(\#[0-9]+\)|\(AND-[0-9]+\)` works if I place it directly in the code in place of `${project.ticketRegEx}`, but not if I put it in `gradle.properties` in place of the regular expression.

Comment: `def issueNumMatcher = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(project.ticketRegEx).matcher(message)` ?